# How to change the grey color of a clip block in the grey timeline in FCPX

Tags: editing, fcpx

in the FCPX timeline, is there a way to change the standard grey color of a clip?  so i can notice it quickly between hundred other grey clips in the timeline ? Imagine the convenience...

Answer (score 1):

Modify > Edit Roles

Choose a colour, then right-click an item in the Browser or in the Timeline to Assign that new Role.

Comment: Ok this sounds promising , but i was already stuck , at choosing the color.

Comment: yes - that can be a problem  ; )